laravel dompdf server error 500 in production vercel
im trying to use download pdf feature with laravel dompdf and in local it works just fine, buat when i deploy it on the server there's a server error 500..
use Pdf;
$pdf = Pdf::loadView('kwitansi.index', [
            'bookings' => [$booking],
            'isMember' => $isMember,
            'keterangan' => $keterangan,
            'totalPrice' => $booking->price,
            'noKwitansi' => $request->no_kwitansi,
            'showTax' => $request->showTax
        ])->setPaper('a5', 'landscape');

        return $pdf->download('kwitansi-' . $request->no_kwitansi . '.pdf');

this is the route:
Route::get('/lapangan/booking/kwitansi', [BookingController::class, 'showKwitansi'])->name('booking.kwitansi');
